# Removing misconfigured NFS datastore on ESXi (4.1)

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs

by mistake I created a non-functional NFS datastore on my ESXi. I can see an error in errorlog (wrong target IP).

The thing is, that I don't see this datastore in the list of datastores, so I can't remove it.

Even more, I'm not able to add any other NFS store, as all attempts end with message that the misconfigured one cannot be created :(

Any suggestions?

THX rezna

Answer (score 1):

If it is listed in `esxcfg-nas -l` from the cli you can try to use `esxcfg-nfs -d` to try and remove it there.

Comment: Keep in mind since this is ESXi not ESX, CLI is not traditionally available. You can use the vCLI tools (http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/) to achieve the same thing, but this requires a licensed vSphere setup. `esxcfg-nas` may be available by enabling SSH access however.

Comment: I don't see any datastores when I try to --list them :(

Comment: what more - i'm not allowed to add datastores using neither esxcfg-nas nor vicfg-nas - fault.RestrictedVersion.summary - but my ESXi is definitely licensed :/

Comment: What license level of ESXi?

Comment: not sure - the only thing I see is 'vSphere 4 Hypervisor licensed for 2 CPU...'

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the NFS export, bounce that particular host, recreate and add again.

Comment: 'nfs export'? where to find this?

Comment: On whatever is exporting the NFS mount to you - a SAN/NAS somewhere I guess - I don't know your environment obviously.

Comment: Ah, the problem is not the side of the NFS mount, the problem is at ESXi itself. I by mistake entered 192.168.3.1 as the NFS host (actually my ESXi address) instead of 192.168.3.7 (my NAS address). Now I only get error regarding not being able to connect to 192.168.3.1, and I'm not able to do anything else (like addin other NAS stores)

Comment: fine but I'm saying you may have to unexport/reexport the NFS mount plus bounce the host before you get to reenter it properly.